# Set activity indicator until image is loaded from server?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I'm new to iOS development so please bear with me.
I'm making a photo-grid using a table view and scroll view.
My question is how could I load an activity indicator until an image downloads from a  server and then display the image and remove the activity indicator?

I'm trying to stay away from third-party library's as I want to understand how it works.

Comment: You should specify how are you going to get the image from the server. If it is using the nsconnection then one of the delegates has the received response delegate method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place an Activity Indicator (via Interface Builder or manually) on your view. Set the property to "hide when not animating".

When doing server call, call [activityIndicator startAnimating] (IBOutlet property).
When returning with actual image, call [activityIndicator stopAnimating]. When stopping, it wil automatically hide.

You can also use the activity indicator in the iPhon/Pad status bar. To do this, use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
Set to NO for hiding it ... (obviously)

Take a look at [dowloading an image async](http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-uiimage-asynchronously/) for a sample of dl'ing an image.
You would stop the activity indicator in the didReceiveData function.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fjakemarsh%2FJMImageCache&ei=UEp7U_W2GoWB8gWShIGgBQ&usg=AFQjCNEc0a59K2wEOlZ2IbapWhVc87kHmg&bvm=bv.67229260,d.dGc

here you could find JMImage cache files that you could use for downloading images.

You have to change UIImageView+JMImageCache.m file

```
    if(i) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            safeSelf.jm_imageURL = nil;

            safeSelf.image = i;

            [safeSelf setNeedsLayout];
            [safeSelf setNeedsDisplay];

            if (completionBlock) {
                completionBlock(i).
            }
        });
```

then use method

```
enter code here
```

{

[yourImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] placeholder:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] completionBlock:^(UIImage *image)
    {
     // remove added activity indicator here

```
}failureBlock:^(NSURLRequest *req,NSURLResponse *resp,NSError *error)
{
// show error message
}];
```

}